# SSRS-DT 2012 Report from 2 Data Sources

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, bids

I'm learning to use SSRS-DT 2012

I need to write a report about assets.

DataSource 1 - View that contains a relationship between a hierarchy number code (AB123) and the name of the hierarchy (Accounting)

DataSource 2 - View that contains the data about the assets and the hierarchy number (AB123).

I'd like the report to contain the Hierarchy Name and the Asset details.

I *think* this is a Lookup, have been getting confused on how to write it b/c in SSRS-DT you write a query as a property of a dataset (If I'm wording that correctly) - I don't know how to write a query that involves 2 data sources.

Am I missing something?

Comment: You could write one query that returns the details fields with repeating summary fields for each detail record within each logical group. Then in your report group you could refer to the summary data using =First(SummaryField.Value).

Answer (score 1):

Use this expression:

```
=lookup(Fields!HierarchyCode.Value,
Fiedls!HierachyCode.Value,Fields!AssetsDescr.Value,"DataSet2")
```

As example I have these datasets:

[image]

Maybe you want to use a tablix for show this report, so I've added one with this data arrangement.

[image]

First column has `Descr` field of my `DataSet1`, the expression at right is used to join it to my `DataSet2` and return the value that corresponds.

This is my expression:

```
=lookup(Fields!Month.Value,Fields!Month.Value,Fields!Total.Value,"DataSet2")
```

Note tablix DatasetName property was set to `DataSet1`

This will preview the following tablix:

[image]

Using the `lookup` function I am getting the corresponding total value from `DataSet2` for every Month in the `DataSet1`.

For more information check [lookup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210531.aspx)